# How to add a ContextMenu per column in the WPF data grid

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, datagrid

This question is similar to [How to add a Column ContextMenu in the WPF DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673617/how-to-add-a-column-contextmenu-in-the-wpf-datagrid), but what I am trying to do is add a different `ContextMenu` PER COLUMN in the WPF Datagrid.

`DataGridTextColumn` is not derived from `FrameworkElement` which has a `ContextMenu` property, so it is not possible to set a `ContextMenu` directly on a `DataGridTextColumn`.  `DataGridCell` also has a `ContextMenu`, but I don't see how to use that for setting a column-specific menu.

The question here is how to add a unique `ContextMenu` for each column (columns are dynamically generated).

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example of how this can be achieved when setting the columns up explicitly:

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Column1Data}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu>
                                    <MenuItem Header="Col 1 Item 1"/>
                                    <MenuItem Header="Col 1 Item 2"/>
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Column2Data}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                            <CheckBox.ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu>
                                    <MenuItem Header="Col 2 Item 1"/>
                                    <MenuItem Header="Col 2 Item 2"/>
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </CheckBox.ContextMenu>
                        </CheckBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

This example includes a `Text` column and a `CheckBox` column. You could modify the `CellTemplate` to suit your requirements, and of course use resources to avoid code duplication.